# Resources for Shortened words for names of countries, languages

Tags: c#

I would like to know where i can find the resource for some shortened words for languages such as 
"en" for "English", "cn" for "Chinese", etc and those for countries such as "ja" for "Japan", "vn" for "Vietnam" etc.

If there is such a resource for me to look up to , how can I change it into corresponding language or country name ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the full list here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, but my problem is to read in only a two letter word i.e "us" then I have to interpret it as "United States". Is there any way else I can do such that I don't need to use a map or a dictionary to store all of them ? I think it is a little overkill to the current problem i am running into, somewhat.

Comment: Read the culture, create a CultureInfo object with CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName) (catch for CultureNotFoundException) and then read the NativeName from the CultureInfo object returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
var langs = System.Globalization.CultureInfo
            .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
            .ToDictionary(ci => ci.Name, ci=>ci.DisplayName);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ISO variants of the ISO 639 standard for language codes, one is a 2 characters list of the most common languages, and the second is a 3 chars list for almost all languages of the world. Look at this: http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php